# Font Size Increase/Decrease change text location

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have HTML pages, in which I am changing font size by using javascript syntax `"document.body.style.fontSize = 20/50/100"`

When I try to change the font size then the HTML moves text up/down according to font increase/decrease and the user is not able to persist at the same text at which the user was before changing the font size.

How can I make the user to stay at the same place as before?

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML pointer"?

Comment: If the user has scrolled a certain percentage of the way down a page, and the font-size changes, the scroll position stays at the same absolute point on the page, not the same percentage of the way down. You'll need to track the scroll position as a percentage of the whole and experiment with adding a modifier due to the characteristics of the font (character height, line height, etc.) and your usage of it.